# Lottie Splash screen and 'AppDelegate.m' error

Tags: ios, c, react-native, lottie

I'm implementing Lottie Splash Screen on my project, I have followed all the steps on Lottie's page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-lottie-splash-screen), but I'm having this error :

> CompileC /Users/danieldobereiner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EmpathoApp-dcyrfhvmvpaykobbglrelwhblgbn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EmpathoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EmpathoApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o /Users/danieldobereiner/Documents/GitHub/Empatho-App-React-Native/ios/EmpathoApp/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'EmpathoApp' from project 'EmpathoApp')
> (1 failure)

```
As I could notice, I think the error is on the 'AppDelegate.m' but I was unable to find the problem, can anyone help me with this

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Flipper version is the problem.

You should check this issue

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31023

[image]